# What purpose does the train, pictured in the Spirited Away movie, actually serve in the ghost world?

Tags: spirited-away

What purpose does the train, pictured in the movie, actually serve in the ghost world?

- The train does not seem to provide service to and from Yubaba's house.
- The train's purpose appears to be to transport some dark shadows one way only. Who are they, and where are they going?
- Strangely, humans used it in the past (Chihiro and her parents use the remnants of the abandoned station to enter the ghost world).
- It is probably not a joke to use this train, as just doing so proves the true love and earns Chihiro respect from Rin ("I take my words back").

The train is clearly the strong symbol of something. What does it represent?

Comment: I thought taking it was worthy of respect for a human because it's full of scary spirits. But you're probably right in thinking there is a deeper meaning.

Comment: The train line doesn't end at Yubaba's house, BTW.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The train connects to different stops and I believe since it is one way it is to service people to an afterlife based on where one wants to reside.

Comment: Yes may be something like Greek Charon's ferry.

Comment: Something like that would make sense.